# using javascript function to be called from code behind under specific condition

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_create" runat="server" 
        Text="Create Weekly Report" 
        OnClick="btn_create_Click" />
```

This is a user button and code behind is

```
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!(dr.HasRows))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(),
        "alert", 
        "openWinContentTemplate();", 
        true);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("entry.aspx");
}
con.Close();
```

I want to call the javascript functionif the first condition is true.
but it is not working.
My javascript function is

```
function openWinContentTemplate() {
    $find("RadWindow_ContentTemplate").show();
}
```

This opens a radwindow if the condition is satisfied.
Its not working could anyone plz help me out.

Comment: So when the page loads have you checked to see if this function `openWinContentTemplate();` has been spit out? (view source)

Comment: Is the btn_create button placed in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: are you inside an updatepanel? and could you show your markup also?

Comment: Ya its working well on page load but I want to make it work from code behind under the if condition.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AJAX to call the method and make the method return something meaningful. If all you want to do is show an element, make the method return a boolean.