# calling javascript function from code behind under some condition

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling ASP.NET Code Behind function from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript)
>   [using javascript function to be called from code behind under specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102946/using-javascript-function-to-be-called-from-code-behind-under-specific-condition)

this is a javascript function.

```
     function openWinContentTemplate() {
     $find("RadWindow_ContentTemplate").show();
     }
```

I want to call this javascript function from code behind on button click under condition as:

```
    protected void button_click()
    {
     if(true)
        //call javascript function here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call in codebehind. Codebehind is on the server, and your script runs on the client. Use the RegisterStartupScript in your codebehind to invoke the script when the browser gets the response.

Comment: Hii     I am using it but it is no working.can u plz explain

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this ....

You can call Js functions as a script registered on the codebehind itself

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("key","value")
```

key is the name you want to give the script

**Example**

```
"PageClose"
```

value is the

```
stringBuilder str = new StringBuilder()
str.Append("<script = language='javascript'>");
str.Append("window.close();");
str.Append("</script>")
```

here instead of using the `window.close` you coud append your `js function as a string`, ideally i put this string builder class and build the script in the constructor if i need it always in the page.

Then use this in the event handler you want to execute the script

```
Page.RegisterStartUp("PageClose",str.ToString());
```

This would place the javascript before the closing  tag of the page thats rendered

```
Page.ClientScriptBlock("PageClose",str.ToString());
```

This would place the JS function after the opening  tag of the page thats rendered

Hope this helps

Comment: its not working .Page.RegisterStartUp("PageClose",str.ToString()); This is not working as Page.RegisterStartUp doesnot work as there is not such method.